# PDO: lastInsertId what value return?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, lastinsertid

in PHP if I use

```
$last_id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

The variable `$last_id` does will get the value of the last row I've inserted in that instance or the latest row of the entire db?

if there are many users that connect and update database at the same time, the last id that I need in my application, will probably not fill the same as the latest of entire db.

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: It's "per connection".... it will return only the id for the last record that was inserted against that connection, irrespective of the number of different users connecting to your site, because each user is working through a different connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$last_id = $db->lastInsertId(); returns last inserted id for this DB conection.remember PDO will always return you the last ID inserted by the current active database connection.